# TitleAreaDialog error message should display at the bottom

Tags: swt, jface

In `TitleAreaDialog` when displaying the error message using `setErrorMessage` the error message is displayed in the top area.

How to display the error message at the bottom.

Can any one helps me...

Comment: Is this `TitleAreaDialog` you are asking about or something else?

Comment: Yes..it TitleAreDialog but need to display at the message at the  bottom

Comment: Why would you want to show the error message at the bottom? Try to be consistent with the rest of the UI. FWIW there is a StatusDialog, that has no title area and shows messages at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

`TitleAreaDialog` does not support putting the error message at the bottom of the dialog.

All the fields involved in the error message code are `private` to the dialog so it isn't possible to override anything to achieve this.

Comment: Any other possible way to display the ErrorMessage at the Bottom

Comment: You will have to write you own code using different methods and a `Label` or something like that.

Comment: Can u help me with a sample...Iam new to SWT

Comment: Sorry, but this is a fair bit of work, too much for a Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StatusDialog` instead of a `TitleAreaDialog` to display a message at the bottom, next to the buttons.

[API Reference](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FStatusDialog.html)